# Cant display rows in a JTable (Values from Database)

Tags: java, sql, database, swing, jtable

Hello dear programmers,

it's my first post and i hope i'm able to describe which kind of problem i have.
I'm German, thats why my classnames are in german. I tried to put in some helpfull comments.

I'm trying to put the values of a database (called "buchungen") into a JTable inside a JPanel.
My JTable shows up but only the headers and no rows..

Here is my class with the JTable inside:

```
public class Verlauf extends SQL{

JTable table = new JTable();
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();


Verlauf(){

    removeAll();

    try {
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM buchungen WHERE Ausführer =     '" + kontoNr + "'");  // kontoNr equals to Ausführer in the database
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    displayData(rs);

    repaint();
}


public void displayData(ResultSet rs)
{

    int i;
    int count;
    String a[];
    String header[] = {"BuchungsNr","Ausführer","Betrag","Aktion","Empfänger"};       //Table Header Values, change, as your wish
    count = header.length;

    //First set the Table header
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        model.addColumn(header[i]);
    }
    table.setModel(model);                      //Represents table Model
    add(table.getTableHeader(),BorderLayout.NORTH);

    a = new String[count];

    // Adding Database table Data in the JTable
    try
    {
        while (rs.next())
        {
            for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                a[i] = rs.getString(i+1);
            }
            model.addRow(a);                    //Adding the row in table   model
            table.setModel(model);              // set the model in jtable
        }
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception : "+e, "Error",     JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

I got the method for the jtable from a other post which i cant find anymore...
I hope someone can help me :)

Edit: The connection to my database is made in another class (called SQL) which works fine         because i can use it from other classes perfectly in the same way i did here.

Greetings Lukas Warsitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the `JTable` header has been added to the container, the table itself has not

```
add(table);
```

Comment: Omg so embarrassing... Thank you very much!